random effect and smoother in GLMMTMB package
For an internship, I have to model using the glmmTMB package.
I am using a tweedie distribution due to my data (a lot of zero, continuous, positive).
I would like to know if it's possible to put a random effet or a covariance structure as ar1 with a smoother with glmmTMB package.
Like in my example :
model <- glmmTMB(AB ~ (1|AN) + scale(T) + scale(Chloa) + scale(Zoo) + s(scale(OeufAvril)), family = tweedie(link="log"), data =data)


When I am trying to run this line, I have the following error :
Error in smooth_terms2[[nonbarpos[i]]] : subscript out of bounds
I don't understand because when I have just one (a random effect or a smoother), I don't have problem. All my variable have the same number of element.
Thanks for helping me.
